# JSONDecodeError при получении объекта из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, файлы, сериализация

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему получаю ошибку при получении списка из файла.

```
import json

with open('file', 'r+') as f:
    json.dump([1, 'hello', 'new'], f)
    json.load(f)
```

В файл записался список:
[1, "hello", "new"]

Теперь load() мне выкидывает ошибку:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Ругается на квадратную скобку?

Переписал код.

```
import json

with open('file', 'w') as f:
    json.dump([1, 'hello', 'new'], f)

with open('file', 'r') as f:
    json.load(f)
```

Ошибка исчезла. Хотя код по сути один и тот же. Почему так происходит? Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы записали в файл данные, а потом пытаетесь прочитать что-то после этих данных ("курсор" находится в конце файла). После записи нужно переместиться на начало файла с помощью `f.seek(0)`, после этого вы сможете прочитать из файла то, что только что записали.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вывод:

```
import json

with open('file', 'r+') as f:
    json.dump([1, 'hello', 'new'], f)
    print(f.read())

with open('file', 'r+') as f:
    print(f.read())
```